# Unable to run the Miner using 2Pac BM1384 USB miner

Tags: mining-hardware, cgminer

I have created a batch file and  I tried to run it. But when I click on the batch file to run it. But the command line window appears for a fraction of a second and then disappears.

```
cgminer.exe  --gekko-2pac-freq 200 -o stratum+tcp://peercoin.ecoining.com:3336 -u username.1 -p x
```

===========================================================
I have tried the below in a batch file,  it gives the below output in the command line

```
cgminer.exe  -o stratum+tcp://peercoin.ecoining.com:3336 -u username.1 -p x
```

---

### cgminer version 4.10.0 - Started: [2017-12-24 04:09:20.602]

```
 (5s):528.0M (1m):507.5M (5m):516.4M (15m):366.6M (avg):516.0Mh/s
 A:0  R:0  HW:2  WU:5.6/m
 Connected to peercoin.ecoining.com diff 16.4K with stratum as user username
```

### Block: c22a0a3f...  Diff:1.61G  Started: [04:15:53.420]  Best share: 98

```
 [U]SB management [P]ool management [S]ettings [D]isplay options [Q]uit
```

### 0: AMU GS-10018:                         | 528.0M / 516.0Mh/s WU: 5.6/m

```
 [2017-12-24 04:09:16.557] Started cgminer 4.10.0
 [2017-12-24 04:09:19.601] Probing for an alive pool
 [2017-12-24 04:09:20.083] Pool 0 difficulty changed to 16384
 [2017-12-24 04:09:20.602] Network diff set to 1.61G
 [2017-12-24 04:15:53.420] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block at height 0
```

============================================================

Is the issue with the script for batch file?

The Syntax for the cgminer.

Run cgminer using following the commands below:

```
cgminer.exe --gekko-2pac-freq 200
-o stratum+tcp://solo.ckpool.org:3333
-u (your username here) -p (your password here)
```

---

Also how to verify the CGi miner is using the Gekko  2Pac BM1384 USB miner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I first started with the 2pac. You didn't mention if you are using a Windows or Linux platform, but the solution is similar either way.

Solution: Ensure your CGMiner binary is compiled to support the Gekko 2Pac. It seems your BM1384 2Pac is not being recognized properly by CGMiner.

This output you provided:

"0: AMU GS-10018: | 528.0M / 516.0Mh/s WU: 5.6/m"

...shows that it is being enumerated as an "AMU" (which is usually ASICMINER block erupters ) It should be "GSC" for a GekkoScience device.  That's also why you are seeing the low hash rate and hardware errors.

So, be sure you have a gekko-enabled CGMiner binary, and also ensure your batch file points to that same correct binary. (correct path)

If you need more detailed help, please state whether you are on a Windows or Linux platform.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the reason why, when you try to run cgminer with the --gekko-freq XXX option, it immediately fails, is because your cgminer is not compiled to support the gekko. (compiled with "--enable-gekko"   When you run it without that option, it works, but it doesn't identify the 2Pac properly, and enumerates the device as "AMU" and doesn't hash properly.

Comment: Your batch commands to run cgminer look correct, no problems there.

Comment: Here is a link to cgminer with gekko that I'm using:     https://github.com/vthoang/cgminer

Comment: Link to all things Gekko Science 2Pac:     https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1764803.0

Comment: Hey, The issue has been fixed. I'm using windows. I have downloaded a new version of cgminer for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

for we linux (debian) geeks, you need to go to the directory you've done the compiling & all the dependancies. (that's a lot of stuff) when you configure the system, you start with root>: ./autogen.sh enable-gekko then after that is done ./configure enable-gekko then "make"  all this stuff is in the cgminer.readme files   I got it to work! In the past I only did the ./autogen.sh and the ./configure, just for giggles i added "make" to my procedure.  Now the frequency command works.  wheeee... who knows?

The command then is: 
./cgminer -o stratum+tcp -u worker1 -p anything --gekko-2pac-freq 200

I've recently done a dist-upgrade to my OS, now the frequency paramater is not working. It is only displaying 3 of my 6 boards, and they are running +350mhz, not what a 150ghz chip is supposed to do.  I'm digging more. Havent found the solution yet.  I will post here when I do find it.  FYI you must be using cgminer 4.1.0 shearch for that on GitHub.  There are a couple forks, I've found no real difference. JLH